# Undefined variable: categories in blade laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade, php-7.1

I am trying to show my categories in site map web page
this is my `CategoryController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Category;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
class CategoryController extends Controller
{

public function site()
   {
    $categories = Category::all();
    #   return view('template.sitemap', compact('categories'));
    #   return view('template.sitemap',['categories' => $categories]);
     return view('template.sitemap')->with(compact('categories'));
    #   return view('template.sitemap')->withData($categories);
    #   return view('template.sitemap')->with('categories',$categories);
    #   return view('template.sitemap', compact('categories'));
  }
}
```

The #  that i use show i use different method of passing variables to  view
i use every method  alone but none of them didn't work.

and this is the part my sitemap blade file  in template folder that i use categories variable    `template.sitempa.blade.php`

```
        <div id="content" class="col-sm-12">
                <h1 class="title"> site map</h1>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs hidden-sm sitemap-icon"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i></div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-6">
                        <ul class="sitemap">
                                <ul>
                                    @foreach($categories as $category)
                                        <li><a href="category.html">{{$category['name']}}</a></li>
                                    @endforeach

                                </ul>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i use every way of get variable and passing but none the didn't work
do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I think there is a typing mistake in `template.sitempa.blade.php`, should be `template.sitemap.blade.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your blade file should be in the directory `template/sitemap.blade.php`, not `template.sitempa.blade.php`

```
public function site()
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    return view('template.sitemap', compact('categories'));
}
```

and

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <li><a href="category.html">{{ $category->name }}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: again the same error
seriously i can't find anything wrong with anywhere of project

Comment: what error show, dd($categories) before return, no data in the category table ? the blade should be in /view/template/sitemap.blade.php, use it by template.sitemap

Comment: don't naming your blade file like this `example.something.etc.blade.php`, instead change like this `example_something_etc.blade.php`

Comment: i write dd($categories) but i dont know where to look for export?
where should i see export of dd?

Comment: put the dd($categories) under the line `$categories = Category::all();` anythings showing on the screen ?

Comment: it show this
"Undefined variable: categories (View: /home/mahdi/.PhpStorm2017.3/Projects/5.6/shop/resources/views/template/sitemap.blade.php)"

Comment: are you going the route of the public function site(), why showing a view error

Comment: it shows this
Collection {#338 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => Category {#339 ▶}
    1 => Category {#340 ▶}
    2 => Category {#341 ▶}
    3 => Category {#342 ▶}
    4 => Category {#343 ▶}
  ]
}

Comment: lol try add this to your web.php Route::get('site', 'CategoryController@site')->name('site');

Comment: i try that and i got this
"Collection {#338 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    0 => Category {#339 ▶}
    1 => Category {#340 ▶}
    2 => Category {#341 ▶}
    3 => Category {#342 ▶}
    4 => Category {#343 ▶}
  ]
}

"

Comment: so remove the dd() line, reload again

Comment: bring the sitemap page but with testss adreees

Comment: so you see your sitemap layout ?

Comment: yes i add this in route and it work
Route::get('sitemap.html','CategoryController@site')->name('sitemap.html');
so i guess i should put route for that function and the blade i want to work 
am i right?

Comment: remove the `.html`, Route::get('site', 'CategoryController@site')->name('site'); means when you go to /site it will goto the action CategoryController@site

Comment: better to learn something from the video first , https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017

Comment: so the route is also necessary?

Comment: tnx for the videos

Comment: yes, always need to write a route point to your action, read again the official document

Comment: tnx i didnt find anything about route on official documentation
thats why i miss this part

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```php
public function site()
{
    return view('template.sitemap')->withCategories(Category::all());
}
```

Then in your view, do:

```php
dd($categories);
```

To know if you are receiving the data. If nothing is wrong, use it as desired:

```php
@foreach($categories as $category)
    <li><a href="category.html">{{$category['name']}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```

Comment: again undefind variable

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function site()
{
$this->data['categories'] = Category::all();
return view('template.sitemap',$this->data);
}
```

In view

```
@foreach($categories as $category)
<li><a href="category.html">{{$category->name}}</a></li>
@endforeach
```